# SQL server linked server to PostgreSQL create iddle connections on PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

My situation: I need to query data from postgreSQL server to SQL server. I installed odbc driver from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi. In SQL server I set up linked server using odbc postgre odbc. Connection is ok and I am able to query data. But my queries create many connections on postgreSQL DB server. Some connections ends in few seconds, some connections ends in few minutes, some connections have idle status and ends in few hours. Many connections creates problems on postgre server.
My queries are very simple - like that "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([postgresqlDBser], 'SELECT abc FROM postgredb_customes_requests')".

I tried to change query and connection timeout in linked server setting, but it didn't help.

[image: 1]

I tried to change ODBC driver (setting ignore timeout, keep alive), but it didn't help too.
Is some possibility to close the connection from my side? Eg. after my query? Or is any other possibility to set odbc connection?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you actually close the connection on the sql server side of the equation?

Comment: NO, I don't know how:). I send only query and I didn't find the commnad for closing connection after query. I read in documentation, that SQL server or ODBC driver end connection immediatelly after query, but it's not true for my case.

Comment: How are you actually querying? Do you have some backend or what?

Comment: I run the queries through Microsoft SQL server management studio and through PowerShell.